# Print @User data from Show (show.html.erb) action to otherpage.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

On my page _user.html.erb, I'm generating user search results. The searched user's credentials (name, email, etc) are successfully populated. However, when my visitor clicks the "Go" button on their resulting username, it currently takes them to show.html.erb (full user profile).

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/go.png", :alt => "Image Description", :action => "show"), user_path(user.id) %>
```

That said, I want to generate this same user data (firstname, lastname, etc) on a page OTHER than show.html.erb, ***e.g.*** otherpage.html.erb.

**I thought this might work:**

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/go.png", :alt => "Image Description", :action => "otherpage"), user_path(user.id) %>
```

Though I assume it doesn't because it's not grabbing the resulting user ID... Does anyone know how I can do this? Help GREATLY appreciated - I'm under a time crunch!

***Note:*** <%= render user %> successfully displays ALL users on otherpage.html.erb, but I want the selected user only.

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def otherpage

     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @user = User.all
      if params[:search]
        @user = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
      else
        @user = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
      end
    end
```

**_user.html.erb**

```
   <div class="name">
          <%= link_to user.firstname, user %> <%= user.lastname %> 
    <%= link_to image_tag("/assets/go.png", :alt => "Image Description", :action => "show"), user_path(user.id) %>

    </div>
```

**otherpage.html.erb**

```
  <%= render @user %>
```

Comment: What does your `rake routes` give as a path for `otherpage`? try `<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/go.png", :alt => "Image Description"), otherpage_path(user.id) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a route for your new action at `config/routes.rb`:

```
get '/otherpage', to: 'users#otherpage'
```

The you can use:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/go.png", :alt => "Image Description", :action => "otherpage"), otherpage_path(user.id) %>
```

As mentioned by @archana you can run `rake routes` from the terminal to see all available routes including the one you just created.

Comment: No dice :/ I get the following error when implementing this:  "Couldn't find User with 'id'= " It looks like it's trying to take me to the path /otherpage.27 , which doesn't exist? I want it to take me to otherpage, which would display data for user 27.

Comment: @Brittany try using `otherpage_path(id: user.id)`

Comment: Getting closer : ) No error, but it displays all users (which it shouldn't, as the ID is now specified successfully). I assume it's because I'm using:   <%= render @user %> in otherpage.html.erb - what should that be instead?

Comment: You're overwriting `@user = User.find(params[:id])` with `@user = User.all`. You should remove the second

Comment: Removed @user = User.all, but page is still displaying all users. Which is strange, as the console says it's succesfully selecting the user Id...

Comment: Based on the code you posted the only possible cause is params[:search] to be present

Comment: Annnd you're a genius. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I have been trying to figure this out forever. I'd hug you if I could, ha ha!!

Comment: Hahaha no problem. I'm glad I could help :)